# Is there a manner to run a scheduled task on apache2 startup with symfony?

Tags: php, linux, background-process, symfony4

I have a backoffice where I can add new devices. When a device is created, I need to open a listening TCP socket to receive data.

I am using Symfony 4 on Debian 9 although my application should work on multiple OS such as Windows or MacOS. The first step is open the socket when the device is created (on controller), but if my server is restarted,

do you know if it is possible to open a TCP socket for each device configured when the application is started (For example, on apache2 startup)?

I was able to create a Symfony command to open the TCP socket but I don't know how to schedule the taks on system startup.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a command (`bin/console make:command`) that fetches all devices

```php
$deviceRepository->findAll()
```

and in a foreach cycle on devices run the code that opens the TCP socket.

```php
foreach ($devices as $device) {
    //you need to write this method in your entity or better in a service
    $device->openTCPSocket();
}
```

To run the command on system boot use the [`@reboot` parameter in crontab](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-execute-cron-job-after-system-reboot/):

```
@reboot /home/myapp/bin/console app:mycommand
```

Or you can write a [systemd service](https://askubuntu.com/a/919059/219209) that run the console script